# How to compare data within one column in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to calculate a column in google spreadsheet.

Column B is a price column (priceUSD). I want to be able to calculate if the price the following day is 5 % higher or more, then it should return a 1. 
Otherwise a 0 (if price is less than 5% higher the following day)

I do not want to add more columns for this only using column D

(column A is a date column)

```
A       B           C       D
date    priceUSD    Addres  Over5

=if(B1*1,05>B2) then return 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, in D3, something like:

```
=ArrayFormula(1*(B2:B900*1,05<B3:B900))
```